# Can't get time to calculate based off of UTC

Tags: java, datetime

I would expect the code below to render the time correct for me in my local timezone (US EST) but I keep getting the time back 5 hours earlier than my current time.  My `userTimeZoneOffset` value is -300 which is the correct offset minutes from UTC for my timezone. `dateAndTimeFormat` is set to "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a" for me.

How can I get the `currentDateAndTime` variable below to calculate based off of UTC rather than my current timezone?

```
String dateAndTimeFormat = i18nUtil.getValue(locale, "dateAndTimeFormat");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateAndTimeFormat);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
if (userTimeZoneOffset != null) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, userTimeZoneOffset);
}
String currentDateAndTime = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
return currentDateAndTime;
```

Comment: Inserting obligatory "use Jodatime" comment

Comment: You're creating a calendar, whose time is the current time, then remove 300 minutes from it, and then are surprised that it's not at the current time anymore? If you want the current time, `Calendar.getInstance()` is sufficient. If you want the current time formatted in your timezone, then `new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(new Date())` is sufficient.

Comment: I already know and understand `new Date()` will give me the time in my current timezone.  I want to get UTC time and apply whatever offset is passed in to it and return that.

Comment: @JBNizet - also, why would `Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))` give me my current time?  One would figure that would give me UTC time.

Comment: What you know is incorrect. A Date doesn't have any time zone. It's a universal instant on the time line. `Calendar.getInstance()` returns the current time. By passing it a timezone, it creates a calendar with the current time, ready to be manipulated in the UTC time zone. So if you ask the number of milliseconds, it will return the same value whatever the time zone is. If you ask it what the day of the week is, then it will return the day of the week in the UTC timezone, for the current time. A given instant in time (the current time) doesn't have the same day of week in USA and Australia.

Comment: Continued: so if you want to display and get information about the current time in your timezone, just use a SimpleDateFormat and a Calendar without specifying any time zone. Yours will be used by default.

Comment: @AndrewJones - and how would I go about doing that?  could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, you should look at Joda-Time instead of the Java DateTime/Calendar library.

To get the current time in UTC, you should import the below packages and call the following line of code:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;

DateTime utcDateTime = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

It looks like you also desire subtracting time from the DateTime you receive. For this, you would call the following method:

```
DateTime estDateTime = utcDateTime.minusHours(5);
```

Joda-Time: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: Yes, this looks like it will work...the servers that are hosting my java code are in a different timezone than where my clients are hence my need to calculate based off UTC and each individual user's timezone offset - thanks.

Comment: Sorry about not answering sooner. I figured this was the type of question that would be answered quickly. One thing to watch out for with Joda is that it's an immutable replacement for Java Calendar and Date. This is great, but it's definitely a gotcha that I want you to be aware of.